# How to check if user have already used the app for 3 days sequenced

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone 8 application and I want to check whether a user has already used my app for 3 days continuously at least once a day. If they do, I will give him/her a tip about a present.

Here I want to know how can I check whether the user have used my app 3 days continuously (needs to use my app at least once every day).

Answer (score 2):

Store the times in your application storage.

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/

**Update:**
This will make it 4 U:

```cs
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e) {
    EnsureCheckThreeDaysInARow();
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) {
    EnsureCheckThreeDaysInARow();
}

public bool EnsureCheckThreeDays() {
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("threeMagicalDay"))
    {
        var data = new List<DateTime>();
        if (data.Count() >= 3 && !data.Any(a => a.Date == DateTime.Now.Date))
            data.Remove(data.Min());
        data.Add(DateTime.Now);
        var someTransform = data.OrderByDescending(a => a).Select(b => new Tuple<int,int,int>(b.Year,b.Month, b.Day)).Aggregate((c,d) => new Tuple<int,int,int>(c.Item1 - d.Item1, c.Item2 - d.Item2, c.Item3 - d.Item3));
        if (someTransform.Item1 == -DateTime.Now.Date.Year && someTransform.Item2 == -DateTime.Now.Date.Month && someTransform.Item3 == 0)
        {
            //There you go...
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle it...
        }
        settings["threeMagicalDay"] = data;
    }
    else 
    settings.Add("threeMagicalDay", new List<DateTime>(){DateTime.Now});

    return false;
}
```

Comment: A little more details would be proper.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the user starts the app record the current date. (Adding it to a list that you store in a file that you keep in isolated storage will probably be the simplest way to do this.)

Then check that list to see if it also includes entries for the last two days also. If it does then you know you're in the situation where you should show the tip.

You'll need to add appropriate logic to remove old data from the list, where appropriate, and probably not add multiple entries per day. You may also want to consider how you handle opening the app multiple times on the 3rd day and if you show the tip multiple times.